# .emacs: c-set-style will delay display of new style until I change the buffer (type a key)

Tags: c, emacs

Dealing with files of different C flavours, I defined the following function and a keyboard mapping to invoke it:

```
(defun my-c-set-gnu-style ()
  "doc string"
  (interactive)
  (setq tab-width 8
        indent-tabs-mode t)
  (c-set-style "gnu")
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x :") 'my-c-set-gnu-style)
```

Now when I open a C file with emacs, and then type  <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> then nothing happens.  Only after I hit some key (and thus I change the code, which is really bad), emacs will re-draw the code according to the new style.

How can I achieve that emacs will re-indent the code right after the respective command has been issued? The need to change the file is really bad.

Version is `GNU Emacs 26.3`.

Comment: What does `C-h f c-set-style` tell you about when/how it takes effect? (I don't know; just suggesting.) What happens when you just call `my-c-set-gnu-style` interactively? Does it do what you want immediately?

Comment: @Drew: Calling `my-c-set-gnu-style` via `M-x` takes immediate action. Help for `c-set-style` doesn't mention any delays or buffering. As an aside the artifact is also with tiny source files. When I move the cursor to a `{`, then the electric-`{` highlight also triggers re-formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about `c-set-style` etc. You say it does some highlighting. Maybe  that's causing a delay or waiting for some condition (maybe some input)? Try using `M-x debug-on-entry c-set-style` (or your function), and step through the debugger to see where/when it seems to be delayed or waiting for input or some buffer change. Maybe it does something only on a buffer-change hook? Maybe check hooks such as these: `after-change-major-mode-hook`, `change-log-mode-hook`, `change-major-mode-after-body-hook`, `change-major-mode-hook`, `first-change-hook`.

Comment: @Drew. Sorry, what that debugger does is impossible to comprehend.  It goes > 10 levels deep and the lines / frames / functions it shows has dozends of arguments. Even if there was an error right in front of me I wouldn't recognize it... Maybe I can add some other action after `c-set-style` that triggers re-draw automatically?

Comment: @Drew: For now I removed the `c-set-style` so that there is still `(setq tab-width 8 indent-tabs-mode t)`, which should also have an effect.  But it doesn't.  I tried `(redisplay t)` afterwards but to no avail.

Comment: @Drew: What seems to work is to issue `(force-window-update)` by hand at the end of the defun. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't related to `c-set-style`.  Changing the TABs mode like in `(setq tab-width 8 indent-tabs-mode t)` should also have an immediate visual effect — which it does not have.

Using `(redisplay t)`  didn't solve the problem, but what worked is `(force-window-update)` at the end of the defun.  Dunno if that's supposed to be issued by hand or whether the requirement is an Emacs bug, though.